# Computer won't boot up with video card. Black screen. Cause?

Tags: boot, video, display, motherboard

- Computer won't boot up with video card.Only black screen. Worked fine
  yesterday. So far i tried:

1.Unplugging all USB. Still only black screen

2.Unplugged video card,ram. Left only motherboard. Worked and could log in to windows.

3.Plugged everything without videocard. Worked and could log in.

4. Made a rollback and uninstalled all drivers. After plugging in video card only black screen appears.

   5. Tried putting my video card into friends computer. Everything worked fine.

   I think that despite that everything works the video card connector in my motherboard is broken.  Should I buy new one or try something else ? 
   Thank you for your time

PC :
PSU: XFX Pro 850 W

Motherboard: Asus Motherboard M5A78L-M USB 3

CPU: AMD AMD FX-4100

CPU cooler: be quiet Shadow Rock 2 180 W TDP

GPU: GTX 960 4GB Asus

RAM: 4GB Hyperx DDR3

HDD: WD 640GB SATA 64mb

Comment: Please be more specific, i mean specify more information (like hardware configuration) so that anyone could help you.

Comment: Added hardware configuration

Answer (score 0):

I looked up your video card and if I found the right one it needs a 6-pin power connection in addition to the slot the card goes in to.

> Only one 6-pin power connector is required to feed the board. The 6-pin connector (75W) and the PCI-Express slot (75W too) provide enough power (150W max) for the Strix GTX 960.

From [enter link description here](http://www.geeks3d.com/20150615/asus-strix-gtx-960-directcu2-oc-4gb-review/)

There appear to be two LEDs, one to show power from the motherboard and one to show power from this secondary connector.  Are you seeing both lit?  Or just one?

Comment: Just the white one ( so i guess its fine)

Comment: Ah, I see, you are correct.

Comment: If you check in your BIOS, it may be that your default video source is defined as the internal one.  If you power up your computer and hook a monitor to your internal port do you get a visible screen?

Comment: Tried that. I also reseted CMOS. Unfortunetly I still get only black screen. Unpluggging the video card however makes it work. I run out of ideas to be honest. I really appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: Try unplugging all your drives and other equipment and see if it boots.  I'm wondering if your power supply can't handle the load.

Comment: It boots up fine. Only inserting video card makes it impossible